# Connecting navigation controller through button on Storyboard crashes app

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I am using a Storyboard for the first time.

Here is a picture:

[image: Image 1]

My app is a TabBar application. From the 'Main' screen I have a settings button, which I would like to connect to the SettingsViewController, which I have embedded in a Navigation Controller (because it has to continue in that manner - to other parts of the settings screen).

Another picture:

[image: Image2]

NOW: I have tried connecting the settings button (command+control drag) to the controller (modal segue)= CRASH. Tried to connect the settings controller (modal segue) = CRASH.

Tried programmatically : creating an IBAction for the settings button an then calling the settings VC, but that crashes too.

Note: This app has many many more screens, but they all work fine. It's just the connection to the Settings VC that Is crashing the app.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Here is the error log:

[image: Image 3]

Comment: You should be connecting the button to the navigation controller -- it's not clear if you tried that.

Comment: Could you add the crash log?

Comment: I added the crash log. That was when it was connected to the navigation controller @rdelmar. I think I have tried everything :)

Comment: What is the rised exception that causes the crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you get the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 
'-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "Eab-23-IvL-view-eGY-e2-X6m" nib but didn't 
get a UITableView.'
```

Which means that your Settings View Controller, which inherits from UITableViewController, does not have an actual UITableView in the storyboard. A fix that will definitely work is to just remove the settings view controller from the storyboard and then drag a Table View Controller in place of the one you removed. Then just proceed to give it the right class in the identity inspector and set back up all of the segues and connections!

Comment: I did that. Still crashes. I stated that in my comment above.

Comment: But what is the rised exception on crash?

Comment: Yeah, but that is the hexadecimal call stack, not very useful! Right on top of that there should be some kind of human-readable message, that should be a bit more helpful in understanding the problem!

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "Eab-23-IvL-view-eGY-e2-X6m" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'  Hmmm. Now what does that mean? The class connected to the view controller (settings) inherits from UITableViewController.

Comment: In the storyboard picture that you posted it doesn't look like there is a UITableView in the settings view controller, why does it inherit from a UITableViewController?

Comment: It SHOULD have a table view. When I created the file I had it inherit from the UITableViewController.. And the class implements the table methods. It usually adds the table view automatically, doesn't it?

Comment: Not unless you dragged a Table View Controller object from the objects library and then assigned it the class of your own view controller that inherits from UITableViewController!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29866/discussion-between-lmvogel-and-micantox)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `UIToolBar` when there is a proper way to handle it, with `UINavigationBar`.
Then you can set a button, connect the button to settingViewController (control+drag), then choose `modal`, set a name to the segue, also control+drag the bar button item to your viewController and connect like this:

```
- (IBAction)btnSettings:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"settingsSegue" sender:sender];
}
```

Then it should work.

Comment: I can put a nav bar on a tabbed view - ?

Comment: You can put nav bar when ever you want.